Waze link opens the app but doesn't start navigation
As the title says, I'm generating Waze links to start navigation to some destination e.g.
https://www.waze.com/ul?ll=40.75889500,-73.98513100&navigate=yes&zoom=6
But this link works as expected only if Waze is already running before opening the link.
Otherwise, the first link opening will just open Waze but won't start the navigation.
Is it some kind of a bug?
I haven't found any mentions of such a problem in https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks
